# generating table using angular directive with completely Dynamic columns(fields) and rows(data))

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to write a directive (using angular) which creates tables with dynamic columns(fields) and rows(data). Column Names will be passes to directive as a string array as follows: `$scope.TableDate.Fields = ['Name', 'LastName','ssn'];` and the rows(data) will be passed as a json object array as follows:

```
    $scope.TableDate.Data = [
        { Name: 'a', LastName: 'b', ssn:456 },
        { Name: 'c', LastName: 'd', ssn:123 }
    ];
```

My code works fine if the only data was dynamic(with fixed column names)
this is my code with fixed column names

```
 App.directive('tableGenerator', function () {
    return {

        template:
            '  <table border="1" ng-Click="Test()">' +
            '<thead>' +
            '<tr>' + '<th>' + 'Name' +  '</th>' +
             '<th>' + 'LastName' + '</th>' +
             '<th>' + 'ssn' + '</th>' +'</tr>' +
            '</thead>' +
            '<tbody' + ' ' + 'ng-repeat="tb in tbodydata"' + '>' +
            '<tr>'+  '<td>' + '{{tb.Name}}' +  '</td>' +
            '<td>' + '{{tb.LastName}}' +  '</td>' +
             '<td>' +  '{{tb.ssn}}' +   '</td>' + '</tr>' +
            '</table>',
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        scope: {
           tbodydata: "=", fields: "="

        },
        link: function ($scope, $element, $attrs, form) {
            $scope.field = $scope;
        }
    };
});
```

But since everything is supposed to be dynamically generated my real code is as below:

```
var App = angular.module('Test', []);
App.directive('tableGenerator', function () {
    return {
        template:
            '  <table border="1">' +
            '<thead>' +
            '<tr>' +
            '<th' + ' ' + 'ng-repeat="fieldName in fields"' + '>' +
             '{{fieldName}}' +
            '</th>' +
            '</tr>' +
            '</thead>' +
            '<tbody' + ' ' + 'ng-repeat="tb in tbodydata"' + '>' +
            '<tr>'+
            '    <td' + ' ' + 'ng-repeat="fieldName in fields"' + '>' +
            '{{tb.fieldName}}' +
            '</td>' +
            '</tr>' +
            '</table>',
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        scope: {
            tbodydata: "=", fields: "="
        },
        link: function ($scope, $element, $attrs, form) {
            $scope.field = $scope;
        }
    };
});
App.controller('TableGenerator', function ($scope) {

    $scope.TableDate = {};
    $scope.TableDate.Fields = ['Name', 'LastName','ssn'];
    $scope.TableDate.Data = [
        { Name: 'a', LastName: 'b', ssn:456 },
        { Name: 'c', LastName: 'd', ssn:123 }
    ];
});
```

and use it in html like below :

```
 <table-generator tbodydata="TableDate.Data" fields="TableDate.Fields"></table-generator>
```

I have to use two ng-repeat one for iterate over date and another for iterate over fields 
the **main issue** is that I can't access the scope value of parent ng-repeat by poing to scope variable of on other ng-repeat like this `{{tb.fieldName}}` which **doesn't work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mistake you are doing is that you are trying to call `tb.fieldName` which is equivalent to `tb = { fieldName: 'myvalue'}`.

You don't want that, don't you?

The way you access a particular property of an object if your property name is a string is by doing this

```
tb[fieldName]
```

[Read more](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects#Objects_and_properties)

From the page above. If your object looks like this:

```
var myCar = new Object();
myCar.make = "Ford";
myCar.model = "Mustang";
myCar.year = 1969;
```

You can access it like this too:

```
myCar["make"] = "Ford";
myCar["model"] = "Mustang";
myCar["year"] = 1969;
```